# Managing User traffic while accessing Web Applications hosted in different Data Centres and depending upon user location keeping performance in mind

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Microsoft Azure, to this question a good and specific solution is required, please help us to find solutions

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-configure-performance-routing-method

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `priority` as the routing method for Azure Traffic Manager. You need to create two different traffic managers for two different data centers in the cloud. After that, you can follow the steps from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-traffic-manager).